# MOSFET as an analog switch / analog multiplexer for high-frequency (few GHz) signals?

Tags: mosfet, rf, high-frequency

Say that I want to design a 16-to-1 analog multiplexer using 16 MOSFETs acting as "relays" (say, n-channel enhancement mode MOSFETs); the source of all 16 MOSFETs are connected to the multiplexer's output, the drain of each MOSFET is connected to one of the inputs, and the gate is the selector for that input (the circuit will ensure that only one gate is set high at a time).

The multiplexing will be slow (a selected signal will remain selected for no less than several microseconds or even milliseconds, and I don't care about the output during the transition to a new selection). However, the analog signals being multiplexed are high-frequency (up to 5GHz or 10GHz).

Is this a reasonable goal?

If so, what sort of specs would I need to look for when choosing the MOSFETs?

Answer (score 2):

It's not reasonable due to the assumption of using Enhancement Mode MOSFETS which have too high capacitance and thus shunt impedance.

16 to 1 is not currently available in 1 package.

A more reasoned choice is more exotic material transistors using SiGe in CMOS.

6 Pole selectors do exist but are quite [expensive to achieve the specs they have.](https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/Switches.html)

I suggest this for your re-[search](https://www.google.com/search?q=SiGe%20in%20CMOS%20mux%2016:1%20GHz)

Comment: "_not reasonable due to the assumption of using Enhancement Mode MOSFETS_" — well, I don't really need to use n-channel enhancement mode MOSFETs;  if depletion mode, or p-channel, or GaN, or SiC, etc. is the right way to go, I'd like to know.  The rest of your answer (if I'm understanding you correctly) seems oriented to digital logic (i.e., multiplexing digital signals), which does not work at all for my application.

Comment: I don't have a commercial solution for you, and due to non-linearity, high-speed logic is much easier than linear analog. So good luck in your research for analog switches, but it does not seem viable at present, so it's still in R&D mode. Or you have to down-convert each signal then sample at a lower IF.

Comment: I wonder whether there may be some conditions that make the solution viable; for example, the datasheet for the ADRF5047 (analog multiplexer going up to a whopping **44 GHz**) shows the interface schematic for the RF inputs as the source of a p-channel enhancement mode MOSFET.  (not sure to what extends that guarantees that the actual circuit inside the actual chip has a MOSFET — as opposed to just having an equivalent functionality at the schematic level?).  They emphatically specify that the source signal _must not have a non-zero DC component_